# Error while runneing select query in sql developer

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 4.1.0.19.
So this can be a very simple issue but I cannot seem to find the solution anywhere as I have just started using SQL Developer.
 I type in this query

```
create table Student(Stu_id INTEGER,Stu_name VARCHAR(60),Stu_email VARCHAR(60))
select * from Student
```

And when I Run the SELECT query, I get an error something like this:

```
Method oracle/jdbc/driver/T4CCallableStatement.isClosed()Z is abstract
```

I have no idea as to why this is happening , this may be very stupid but I cannot seem to find a solution.
BTW I am using Oracle 11g version.

Comment: In a reply to an answer by another poster (now deleted by that responder), you said you have TWO statements: the CREATE TABLE and then the SELECT. But in your post you don't have the semicolons you have in that reply to the deleted answer, and you say "I type in **this query**" - which is singular, not plural. Please edit your post to correct the grammar and to add the semicolons - I read your post exactly the same way as that other responder, and I saw your corrections only there. They belong in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

How did you install SQL Developer? [Can you download the zip off of OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) and extract it to a fresh directory and try running it from there?

Your error message indicates [something VERY bad is wrong with one of the drivers](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3954341). Which makes me wonder if you messed with one of the JARs or are attempting to use an old Oracle Client with a THICK connection.

Comment: I was given the setup by someone. Sure let me just download the zip. I'll update you.

Comment: what do your connection properties look like and what version of Java are you running?

Comment: The error doesn't mean that "something VERY bad is wrong", it means the driver is very old (pre-Java 6), as `Statement.isClosed` was introduced in Java 6 / JDBC 4.0

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  And for the driver to be very old means something very bad is wrong.